# pywinauto - How to identify GUI objects

Tags: python, python-3.6, pywinauto

I am fairly new to Python and I am having trouble identifying GUI objects that I am hoping to control using pywinauto.

Following [this example](https://pywinauto.github.io/) with the below code, I am able to open Notepad.exe and select "Help" from the Menu object.

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
# Run a target application
app = Application().start("notepad.exe")
# Select a menu item
app.UntitledNotepad.menu_select("Help->About Notepad")
# Click on a button
app.AboutNotepad.OK.click()
# Type a text string
app.UntitledNotepad.Edit.type_keys("pywinauto Works!", with_spaces = True)
```

This is pretty cool, but I want to apply this to a more practical example. What I am trying to do is open Excel using `app = Application().start(r"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE")` and select "Blank Workbook" from the menu pane that pops up when you start Excel 2016 - thereby opening a new workbook.

[image]

I've targeted the object using UISpy and identified that the name is "Blank workbook". Using the above example code, what is the line of code I should execute that will select this object to open a new workbook? And more importantly, how do I figure that information out for myself?

[image]

I am using Python 3.6.1. In an unrelated question - I found it interesting that I'm able to open "notepad.exe" without the fully qualified name, but opening Excel requires `app = Application().start(r"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE")` - I'm not sure why this is the case, but that's a question for another day...

Answer (score 1):

Use MS-Spy for object identification

[image: MS-SPY Object Spy]

https://github.com/munnasarfraz/SPY.git

Answer (score 0):

You can use external tools like SWAPY, pyinspect to identify the objects names.
a full list can be found here: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Regarding the python usage, you can trigger print_control_identifiers() function on each of pywinauto dialog objects. the function shows all the dialog's objects: buttons/labels/checkboxes etc.. you can read about it via here:
https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/code.html#controls-reference

So basically, try app.print_control_identifiers() check if the button's name is there and if it does just use getattr(app, X).click() while X is the button's name.

Answer (score 0):

1. As I can see in your question, you already know about UISpy, (I prefer inspect.exe for Windows). Such tools help find UI objects and their properties.
   We can use properties like AutomationId, classname etc to access the UI objects.

[image]

Here is the code snippet to open blank workbook in EXCEL.

```
from pywinauto import Application
import time
app = Application(backend="uia")
excelApp = app.start(r"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\EXCEL.EXE")
time.sleep(5)
wind = excelApp.windows()
title = wind[0].get_properties()[u'texts']
handle = excelApp.window(title = title[0])
child = handle.child_window(auto_id="AIOStartDocument")
child.click_input()
```

Also, you should wait() method instead of sleep time, that is a better practice.

2. Another way is to get the object for the Excel mainwindow and then use the AccessKey (shortcut key) for the action.

If you manually open excel and press ALT key you will find out the shortcuts.
[image]

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application().start(cmd_line=u'"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\EXCEL.EXE" ')
xlmain = app.Excel
xlmain.wait('ready')
xlmain.type_keys("%L")
```